# From where are variables in configure.ac substituted?

Tags: autotools

I am trying to understand the `configure.ac` file for the `libXrender` package:

```
...
AC_INIT(libXrender, [0.9.8], [https://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=xorg], [libXrender])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([Makefile.am])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign dist-bzip2])
AC_PROG_LIBTOOL

# Require X.Org macros 1.8 or later for AC_PROG_INSTALL
m4_ifndef([XORG_MACROS_VERSION], [m4_fatal([must install xorg-macros 1.8 or later before running autoconf/autogen])])
XORG_MACROS_VERSION(1.8)
XORG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS
XORG_CHECK_MALLOC_ZERO

# Check render configuration, strip extra digits from package version to
# find the required protocol version
if test "$VERSION" = "" ; then
       VERSION=$PACKAGE_VERSION;
fi
RENDER_VERSION=[`echo $VERSION | sed 's/^\([0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\).*$/\1/'`]
AC_SUBST(RENDER_VERSION)

# Obtain compiler/linker options for depedencies
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(RENDER, x11 renderproto >= $RENDER_VERSION)

# Check for _XEatDataWords function that may be patched into older Xlib release
SAVE_LIBS="$LIBS"
LIBS="$RENDER_LIBS"
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([_XEatDataWords])
LIBS="$SAVE_LIBS"

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile
        src/Makefile
        xrender.pc])
AC_OUTPUT
```

I understand that `AC_INIT`, and `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE`, etc. are macros that are specified in the GNU Autotools installation directories, and `XORG_MACROS_VERSION`, etc. are specified in the X.org package installation directories (I think).

What I don't understand is, from where will variables like `$VERSION`, `$PACKAGE_VERSION` and `$LIBS` get their values? Isn't `configure.ac` supposed to be like, the "top-level" input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't configure.ac supposed to be like, the "top-level" input file?

I would certainly make that characterization myself, but what you and I mean by it must differ, because I don't see how it bears on your central question:

> What I don't understand is, from where will variables like $VERSION,
>   $PACKAGE_VERSION and $LIBS get their values?

Remember always that `Autoconf` is a *code generator*.  It builds a shell script from the input file you present to it, using a custom configuration of the `m4` macro processor, a built-in macro library, and any additional macros provided to it.  Many of these macros emit shell code that causes shell variables to be defined when the resulting `configure` script runs.  These variables belong to `configure`; they are just text to Autoconf itself.  (Generally.  There are, in fact, one or two gotchas in this area.)

Different variables are set and/or modified by shell code produced by different macros.  For example, [`AC_INIT`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Initializing-configure.html#index-AC_005fINIT-22) emits code that defines `$PACKAGE_VERSION`.  I think it's also responsible for `$VERSION`, but I don't find that documented.

On the other hand, some variables take their initial values from the environment in which `configure` is run.  `$LIBS` is one of these.  In the (usual) event that it is not set in the environment, it follows from ordinary shell behavior that the initial value is effectively empty.  This particular variable is updated by code generated by [the `AC_CHECK_LIB` and `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` macros](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Libraries.html), and possibly others.

Coming back to the nature of Autoconf, perhaps your confusion arises from a failure to appreciate the distinction between a macro and a function.  Autoconf *expands macros* recursively to produce a shell script.  The semantics of the resulting script are whatever follows from the resulting code.  Autoconf macros do not provide any scoping for for shell variables that appear in the resulting script.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I believe you pointed out my confusion correctly. I was thinking from the point of view of functions, i.e. where will "configure" be called from, so that the values for those variables can be passed in. I now realize that it is just macro expansion - autoconf just expands all the macros from configure.ac using definitions found elsewhere, and in those definitions will also be some variable definitions, which end up in "configure". It is these indirectly-defined variables that are being referred to in the configure.ac shown above.

Comment: The references to those variables in configure.ac will also end up in "configure", but *after* the expanded versions of the previous macros like AC_INIT, which will contain the definitions of those variables.